# Get inner-most elements from triple nested list Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have list

`players = [[['QB1',7000,20],['RB1',4500,12],['RB2',3800,11]],
[['QB1',7000,20],['RB2',3800,11],['RB1',4500,12]]]`

How do I get the first element of each inner-most lists ('QB1', 'RB1' and 'RB2' from the first "secondary," if you will, list) to check if they are the same, however disordered labels as those in another secondary list (they are in this case as both secondary lists contain 'QB1', 'RB1' and 'RB2')?

EDIT:

My desired out is `[['QB1','RB1','RB2'],['QB1','RB2','RB1']]`. I want to have some way of identifying that these are, for my purpose, the same list.

Comment: what is your desired output? what do you mean by `inner-most elements` ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar Good question, I should've been more clear - I've edited the original question to include my desired output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
output = [[i[0] for i in a] for a in players]
```

The `output` will be like this:

```
[['QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2'], ['QB1', 'RB2', 'RB1']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I had actually been trying `[i[0] for i in a for a in players]`, I see why your solution works as opposed to mine though

Answer (score 3):

you can use recursive search for that and get first element of each list or whole list

```
players = [[['QB1',7000,20],['RB1',4500,12],['RB2',3800,11]],[['QB1',7000,20],['RB2',3800,11],['RB1',4500,12]]]
def retrive_first(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) == list:
            retrive_first(item)
        else:
            print "returning ---> ", lst[0]
            return lst[0]

print retrive_first(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
[list(map(itemgetter(0), player)) for player in players]
```

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
print(list(zip(players))[0])
```

Or:

```
print([i[0] for i in players])
```

Comment: The first returned `([['QB1', 7000, 20], ['RB1', 4500, 12], ['RB2', 3800, 11]],)` and the second `[['QB1', 7000, 20], ['QB1', 7000, 20]]`